# Minecraft commandblock blockbreacker with dropped item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I use to detect an armor stand with an cobblestone, 2 blocks below. If so then he place air there. This commmand is in an repeat command block with Always Active.

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ cobblestone -1 /setblock ~ ~-2 ~ air
```

The second command was there to spawn the cobblestone but only if an emerald block is under the armor stand. This command is in an chain command block alway active.

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ emerald_block -1 /summon Item ~ ~-2 ~-1 {Item:{id:cobblestone,Count:1,}}
```

The problem now is that I want it that the cobble only drops where it get broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you want the cobble to drop where it gets broken you might want to add a block handler "destroy" to simulate it as if a player broke it in survival mode.
This would be your setblock command
`/setblock ~ ~-2 ~ air 0 destroy`
If you have any problems then please reply so I can help you further!